# Issue regarding http POST api call using ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, net-http

I am going to access the Riskscreen api to authenticate users. To test the api I have written a ruby code snippet to make sample POST call to get the number of tokens I have from the Riskscreen api.

My code is:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'json'

@toSend = {}.to_json

uri = URI.parse("https://api.riskscreen.com/api/v1/user/tokens")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
header = {'api-key': 'my api key','Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, header)
req.body = "[ #{@toSend} ]"
res = https.request(req)


puts "------------"
puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Response 400 Bad Request
```

If I change the header line to

```
header = {'api-key'=> 'my-api-key','Content-Type'=> 'application/json', 'Accept'=> 'application/json'}
```

then I am getting this error:

```
Response 401 Unauthorized
```

Sticking with this for a while. Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Are you sure the request body is OK?
Can you add a link to the API description?

Comment: Here it is: https://search.riskscreen.com/help/guide-api

Comment: This requires an account.

Comment: I have edited the post and have given the credentials. Please check.

Comment: I think you shouldn't share your private information to stackoverflow( username, password, api-key). It is risk.

Comment: Okay. But it seems to access the documentation, credentials are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header's keys must be String instead of Symbol

```
header = {'api-key' => 'my api key','Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
```

Another issue is `net/http` is capitalize header automatically, `api-key` -> `Api-Key` which cause `Authorization Error` on your server. One solution is to create new class to wrap `api-key` to prevent Ruby do that

```
class HeaderCaseSensitive < String
  def capitalize
    self
  end

  def split(*args)
    super.each do |str|
      HeaderCaseSensitive.new(str)
    end
  end

  def to_s
    self
  end
end
```

Then change header:

```
header = {HeaderCaseSensitive.new('api-key') => 'xxxx','Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
```

To sum up, following code will work:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'json'

class HeaderCaseSensitive < String
  def capitalize
    self
  end

  def split(*args)
    super.each do |str|
      HeaderCaseSensitive.new(str)
    end
  end

  def to_s
    self
  end
end

@toSend = {}.to_json

uri = URI.parse("https://api.riskscreen.com/api/v1/user/tokens")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
header = {HeaderCaseSensitive.new('api-key') => 'xxx','Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
https.set_debug_output($stdout)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, header)
req.body = "[ #{@toSend} ]"


res = https.request(req)


puts "------------"
puts "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
```

Comment: @Abhradip you should also contact RiskScreen and ask them to fix this on their side, as headers as not meant to be case-sensitive! You will also want to ask them to change your access token...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try remove:

```
req.body = "[ #{@toSend} ]"
```

and replace by:

```
req.set_form_data({})
# or 
req.body = "{}"
```

Sorry, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Abhradip 401 is different than 400, check if you authenticated properly and with correct api key.

Comment: There is no issue with api-key. It is working fine in POSTMAN

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why it not work. I try set ```http.set_debug_output $stderr``` to see what Ruby request, api-key is included in header. I think you should contact Riskscreen support. Goodluck!